# Object relational SQL - iterate over collections (TABLE OF REF) and VARRAY

Tags: sql

i have a problem.

i need to iterate over an TABLE OF REF Order_Typ. And then i need to iterate over the Positions of the Order_Typ to get/select the Nr.

I have no idea how to do this...  please help me

[image: SQL Scenerio - Example]

Comment: `JOIN` is the idea

Comment: i think you dont use a join in object relational SQL. The purpose of REFs is that you dont need JOINs...

Comment: I think it would be helpful to tag the ORDBMS that you are using since the implementations tend to vary widely.